# Web App Dependencies (JS, CSS) fail to load when using Istio Gateway and VirtualService

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, presto, istio

I'm using Helm to deploy various packages (PrestoDB, Apache Spark etc), and for each of these tools I am just using Helm to deploy them using the basic configuration.

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/spark

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/presto

Both deploy just using a ClusterIP service for exposing the Web UI, which I then create a gateway and VirtualService using Istio to the Web Apps can be exposed outside the cluster.  After deploying PrestoDB using Helm, this is the Gateway and VirtualService I deploy:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: presto-gateway
  namespace: warehouse
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: presto
  namespace: warehouse
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - presto-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /ui
    route:
    - destination:
        host: presto-warehouse
        port:
          number: 8080
EOF
```

This works successfully, however when i go to load the PrestoDB Web UI, I only see text, and I can see in the console that it appears almost all of the JS/CSS dependencies are failing to load.  I can see that when i go to "ingressgateway/ui", there is just some plain text, and all of the dependencies appear to be just loading from "ingressgateway", and not "ingressgateway/ui/vendor/xxx.js" etc.  Is there a way to re-route the web app from trying to load dependencies from the base domain and prefix it with "/ui" so that it will load?  This happens with multiple services when I try to launch them and sit them behind the ingress gateway - spark and others work just fine, but the web apps have trouble loading dependencies and you can only see plain text.

Thanks

Comment: What K8s and istio versions You have? Which platform/infrastructure do You have? You can install [istioctl 1.4.0](https://istio.io/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/istioctl/) and try to run istioctl x analyze -k to see if it can find any problems within istio mesh. You could try use MTLS [permisive mode](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authentication/mtls-migration/) and check with that so we would be sure it's not policy problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since You use istio Did you enable [sidecar injection](https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/) in your cluster?

> Is there a way to re-route the web app from trying to load dependencies from the base domain and prefix it with "/ui" so that it will load?

If i understand You correctly you could use rewrite, which exist in virtual service.

There is a good example which i found in another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023560/12461138)